# Removing XML Nodes by Comparing the List items

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-core, c#-4.0

I've been working on removing few XML nodes from an XML string.My requirement is to remove the XML nodes that match the list items. I was trying to get the childNodes and check whether the childNode's Name is in the properties list. I've generated the list of Properties present in the MovieDetails class.

```
public class MovieDetails 
    {
        public string MovieName { get; set; }
        public string MovieId { get; set; }
        public string MovieGenre { get; set; }
    }
```

MyXml:

```
<MovieContent>
  <MovieDetails>
      <MovieName>Movie_Name_1</MovieName>
      <MovieId>MovieId_1</MovieId>
      <MovieGenre>MovieGenre_3</MovieGenre>
      <AdditionalInformation>HAHAHHAHA</AdditionalInformation>
  </MovieDetails>
  <MovieDetails>
      <MovieName>Movie_Name_2</MovieName>
      <MovieId>MovieId_2</MovieId>
      <MovieGenre>MovieGenre_3</MovieGenre> 
      <AdditionalInformation>FOOOO</AdditionalInformation>
  </MovieDetails>
  <MovieDetails>
      <MovieName>Movie_Name_3</MovieName>
      <MovieId>MovieId_3</MovieId>
      <MovieGenre>MovieGenre_3</MovieGenre> 
      <AdditionalInformation></AdditionalInformation>
  </MovieDetails>
</MovieContent>
```

I tried using a for loop but couldn't get my desired result.But from the below code I could remove on 1 node everytime.

```
 var movieDetailsNode = xmlContent.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
 var properties = typeof(MovieDetails).GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    foreach (XmlNode node in movieDetailsNode )
    {
       var childNodeList = node.ChildNodes;
       for (int i = 0; i < childNodeList.Count; i++)
       {
           var childNodeName = childNodeList[0].Name;
           if (properties.Contains(childNodeName))
           {
               childNodeList[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(childNodeList[i]);
           }
        }
     }
```

Can anyone please help out in achieving the below resultant xml

Resultant XML:

```
<MovieContent>
  <MovieDetails>
      <AdditionalInformation>HAHAHHAHA</AdditionalInformation>
  </MovieDetails>
  <MovieDetails>
      <AdditionalInformation>FOOOO</AdditionalInformation>
  </MovieDetails>
  <MovieDetails>
      <AdditionalInformation></AdditionalInformation>
  </MovieDetails>
</MovieContent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way would be to use [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview) from the [`System.Xml.Linq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq?view=netcore-3.1) namespace to remove the nodes from your properties collection. Using a `HashSet<string>` makes sense here since the names should be unique and lookup times are constant instead of linear.

```
var properties = typeof(MovieDetails)
    .GetProperties()
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .ToHashSet();

// Or just var properties = new HashSet<string> { "MovieName", "MovieId", "MovieGenre" };

var doc = XElement.Load(@"C:\input.xml");

doc.Descendants("MovieDetails")
   .Elements()
   .Where(e => properties.Contains(e.Name.LocalName))
   .Remove();

doc.Save(@"C:\output.xml");
```

**Explanation**

- Fetch the `MovieTitle` nodes with [`Descendants()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendants?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_Linq_XContainer_Descendants_System_Xml_Linq_XName_).
- Get all child elements with [`Elements()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.elements?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_Linq_XContainer_Elements).
- Filter out elements that don't exist in the hash set with [`Enumerable.Where`](http://crosoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1) and [`HashSet<T>.Contains(T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?view=netcore-3.1).
- Remove nodes from parent node with [`Remove()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.remove?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_Linq_XNode_Remove).

**output.xml**

```
<MovieContent>
  <MovieDetails>
    <AdditionalInformation>HAHAHHAHA</AdditionalInformation>
  </MovieDetails>
  <MovieDetails>
    <AdditionalInformation>FOOOO</AdditionalInformation>
  </MovieDetails>
  <MovieDetails>
    <AdditionalInformation></AdditionalInformation>
  </MovieDetails>
</MovieContent>
```

Comment: Is there possibility to retrieve the xml nodes that are not there in List<string> and store in a variable

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
            var movieDetailsNode = xmlContent.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
            var properties = typeof(MovieDetails).GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
            foreach (XmlNode node in movieDetailsNode)
            {
                var childNodeList = node.ChildNodes;
                for (int i = 0; i < childNodeList.Count; i++)
                {
                   // replace '0' with 'i'
                    var childNodeName = childNodeList[i].Name;
                    if (properties.Contains(childNodeName))
                    {                       
                        childNodeList[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(childNodeList[i]);
                        // add decrement of 'i' here
                        i--;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: When the 0th node removed.The next node is taking the 0th position.